# Combine values of columns and state condition in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4'], 'b': ['True', 'False', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'False']})
 a      b
0  1   True
1  1  False
2  1   True
3  2   True
4  2   True
5  2   True
6  3   True
7  3   True
8  4  False
9  4  False
```

I want to combine all numbers in *column a* with the same numbers. Moreover, I want to state in *column b*, if all values of *b* are true for a specific *a* to set it true or if at least one is false to set it false.

The result should therefore look like this:

```
 a      b
0  1  False
1  2   True
2  3   True
3  4  False
```

How do I achieve this?
I tried it with groupby, but I'm not able to find a suitable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) for test if all values are `True`s:

```
#if necessary convert strings to boolean
df['b'] = df['b'].map({'True':True, 'False':False})

df = df.groupby('a', as_index=False)['b'].all()
print (df)
   a      b
0  1  False
1  2   True
2  3   True
3  4  False
```